# Specific Round Corner of NSView

Tags: macos, nsview, round-corner

I want a specific corner of NSView  with radios but I can't figure it out how to do it.
for all corners, I am using

```
class StyledButton: NSView {
let roundLayer: CALayer = CALayer()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.layer?.addSublayer(roundLayer)
    roundLayer.frame = self.bounds
    roundLayer.cornerRadius = 3
    roundLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `maskedCorners`:

```
    layerMinXMinYCorner = bottom left corner
    layerMaxXMinYCorner = bottom right corner
    layerMaxXMaxYCorner = top right corner
    layerMinXMaxYCorner = top left corner
```

Here is an example to round only `bottom right and top right` corners:

```
        let rightRoundView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 128, height: 128))
        rightRoundView.wantsLayer = true
        rightRoundView.layer?.cornerRadius = 25
        if #available(OSX 10.13, *) {
            rightRoundView.layer?.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```